# How do I improve the sharpness of canny edges to improve detection?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, canny-operator

I'm trying to detect text that's overlaid onto a moving background. I've used canny to almost perfectly remove the background but I'm left with almost blurry text that I'm not able to get clear detections on.

For example with canny, I can't seem to get better than about a 96% match. Whereas if I swap back to just using `matchTemplate` without canny I can get about a 98% match on the same image.

[image]

I've got thousands of images and some like the above are simple Latin characters, but I've also got a lot of Asian character sets and Cyrillic script in there too. For example, while the above example does return a positive detection at 96% the below is down in the 40-50% mark.

[image][image]

I load my images into an array, and generate canny frames to run detection on. I use `ImageGrab` to get a crop of the screen, load that into a numpy array, blur the edges with `GuassianBlur` and then run my detection on the blurred images. I then return `edges` to run detection on.

For my actual detection, I use `matchTemplate`. I iterate through my loaded images, grabbing the maximum value from the detection and if it's greater than 90, I print it to the terminal.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import glob
from PIL import ImageGrab

def loadImages(directory):
    image_list = []
    for i in directory:
        img = cv.imread(i, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        image_list.append((img))
    return image_list

def videoLoop():
    haystack_img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(750, 33, 1150, 70))
    haystack_img_np = np.array(haystack_img )
    img_blur = cv.GaussianBlur(haystack_img_np, (3,3), 0)
    edges = cv.Canny(image=img_blur, threshold1=200, threshold2=500)
    return edges

def shipDetection(image_list, threshold, haystack, a):
        for i in image_list:
            result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack, i, cv.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
            min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(result)
            if max_val >= 90:
                print(max_val)

def detection():
    test = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\*.png")
    images = loadImages(test)

    while True:
        window = videoLoop()
        shipDetection(images, 0.96, window)

detection()
```

The images I want to run detection were generated using this;

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == "__main__":

    image_dir = r"C:\test\images"
    output_dir = r"C:\test\canny"

    for _, _, image_names in os.walk(image_dir):
        for image_name in image_names:
            if '.png' in image_name:
                filepath = os.path.join(image_dir, image_name)
                dstpath = os.path.join(output_dir, image_name)
                image = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (3,3), 0)
                edges = cv2.Canny(image=img_blur, threshold1=200, threshold2=400)
                cv2.imwrite(dstpath, edges)
```

Comment: Using binary filters like `threshold()` or `adaptiveThreshold()` would give much better results. Canny its doing its thing but the characters are too tiny.

Comment: Thank you Karl, thresholding is giving me return rates around 97-98% but with so many images that quite frequently returns a false positive. I might be asking too much but I was wanting to push that up towards 98/99% accuracy.

Comment: You can always use some erode/dilate filters to help you get better bounding boxes around those characters which could then be sent to Tesseract or some Neural Network or SVM for classification/recognition purposes.

Comment: I've been treating them as images rather than text up until now, do you think treating them as text would be more successful? I figured the shapes seemed fairly prominent and should've been pretty easy to find a `threshold` match with but alas, it isn't.

Comment: How about a [color threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html) instead?